# Getting the element ("<a>") that called the JavaScript function defined in its onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I just started using bootstrap and I want to write a JavaScript function to close a popover. It's very easy to close a popover, you just select the popover html element and call popover("hide") on it.

I want to write a generic function that will search upwards from the current element until it finds a popover element, and then it will call close on it. Let's call this function `CloseParentPopover()`.

Now, ideally, I would be able to have any HTML link (`<a>`) that exists inside a popover to call this function onclick, and it should close the popover that the link resides in. Something like

```
<a href="#" onClick="CloseParentPopover()">...</a>
```

And that would 'just work'.

The function to 'search upwards until we find a popover' is easy enough to implement. But I was wondering how exactly I would get which element was the one being clicked on. I need some way to know which link was clicked. Something like

```
<a href="#" onClick="CloseParentPopover(this)">...</a>
```

but obviously that is not valid.

Comment: why is it not valid?

Comment: You might want to try it before saying it's invalid. ;)

Comment: that is a valid statement ...

Comment: oh my god really. I totally just made it up. Ok thanks! Someone say that as an answer so I can close this bad boy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* a valid statement - you should try things before assuming they're wrong :)